# Continuation of data validation after a try catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Okay, so I have a form in Visual Studio 2012. I want to validate user input in textboxes to check that they meet certain requirements etc. I have the string ones down, but the last one to validate is an integer.
I want to check that the data input in the textbox is a number, and if it isn't, add an error message to an existing error message variable. If it is a number, I then want to check that it's within a certain range

My problem arises when the input is not a number. A string, for example. The try catch that I'm using to add to the error message if the input is not an integer works, but after that executes successfully, the code continues and throws an exception when it tries to process the string.

This is all of the code:

```
    public string IDValid(string MotherBaseID,
                      string CodeName,
                      string AbilityRank,
                      string AssignedTo,
                      string Affiliation,
                      string HairColour,
                      string Ethnicity,
                      string DateJoined,
                      string AtMotherBase,
                      Int32 YearsAtBase)


///this function is used to validate the data in a new ID entry
///it accepts 9 parameters and returns a string containing the text of any errors (if any)
///if no errors, it returns a blank string
{
    string ErrorMsg; //var to store any error message
    ErrorMsg = ""; //initialise the var with a blank string

    //if the string is less than 1 char or more than 6
    if (MotherBaseID.Length < 1 | MotherBaseID.Length > 6)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The ID number must be between 1 and 6 characters, ";
    }

    if (CodeName.Length < 3 | CodeName.Length > 15)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The codename must be between 3 and 15 characters, ";
    }
    if (AbilityRank.Length < 2 | AbilityRank.Length > 3)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The ability rank must be between 2 and 3 characters, ";
    }
    if (AssignedTo.Length < 2 | AssignedTo.Length > 10)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The assigned to section must be between 2 and 10 characters, ";
    }
    if (Affiliation.Length < 7 | Affiliation.Length > 15)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The affiliation must be between 7 and 15 characters, ";
    }
    if (HairColour.Length < 3 | HairColour.Length > 10)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The hair colour must be between 3 and 10 characters, ";
    }
    if (Ethnicity.Length < 4 | Ethnicity.Length > 10)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The ethnicity must be between 4 and 10 characters, ";
    }

    if (AtMotherBase.Length < 3 | AtMotherBase.Length > 5)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The AtMotherbase field must be 'True' or 'False, ";
    }

    if (DateJoined.Length < 10 | DateJoined.Length > 11)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "The date entered must be in the DD/MM/YYYY format, ";
    }

    try
    {
        //var to store the DateJoined 
        DateTime Temp;
        //assign the date to a temporary var
        Temp = Convert.ToDateTime(DateJoined);
    }
    catch
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "Date entered is not a valid date";
    }

    try
    {
        YearsAtBase = Convert.ToInt32(YearsAtBase);
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "Please enter a number into the YearsAtBase field ";
    }
    if (YearsAtBase < 1 | YearsAtBase > 15)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "YearsAtBase must be a number between 1 and 15 ";
    }



        if (ErrorMsg == "")
        {
            //return a blank string
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            //return the errors string value
            return "There were the following errors : " + ErrorMsg;
        }


    }
```

This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
try
    {
        YearsAtBase = Convert.ToInt32(YearsAtBase);
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "Please enter a number into the YearsAtBase field ";
    }
    if (YearsAtBase < 1 | YearsAtBase > 15)
    {
        //set the error message
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg + "YearsAtBase must be a number between 1 and 15 ";
    }
```

I want the code to check that the YearsAtBase input is an integer, and if it isn't then tell the user, but if it is, carry on the code as normal until it hits the return which ends the validation. Am I being stupid here?

Comment: One way is to just put your `if (YearsAtBase < 1 | YearsAtBase > 15)` code inside the `if (ErrorMsg == "")` block.

Comment: If I do that I get Error 'clsOverview.IDValid(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, int)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You should look at `int.TryParse()` and `DateTime.TryParse()`; catching exceptions in this manner to validate values is very inefficient.

Comment: I'm confused - `YearsAtBase` is an `Int32` value but you're trying to convert it to an `Int32` and expecting it to fail?

Comment: You are converting YearsAtBase to Int yet its data type is int? doesn't make sense

Comment: Yeah, I'm very to new to this. I basically tried a whole bunch of different things to get it to work. I'll take your comments into consideration and update back here shortly. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this by using a try if else catch format. Quite simple looking back, but hey. Thanks everyone for the comments.